# When was "Retcon" (amnesia pill) first used in the Doctor Who universe?

Tags: doctor-who, torchwood

In a recent episode of Doctor Who ("Face the Raven"), the drug Retcon, is utilized to erase a character's memory of the previous day. I've previously seen this utilized by Jack Harkness, in *Torchwood*, to prevent characters from remembering that Torchwood exists.

When was Retcon first used to achieve this short term amnesia?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Retcon was introduced in *Torchwood*, and first appeared in the first episode, "Everything Changes"; Jack spikes Gwen's drink with it:

> **Jack:**  How's your drink?
>
> **Gwen:** Have you poisoned me?
>
> **Jack:** Don't be so dramatic. It's an amnesia pill. My own recipe, with a touch of denial and a dash of Retcon. Wake up tomorrow morning, you'll have forgotten everything about Torchwood. Worse still, you'll have forgotten me, which is kind of tragic.
>
> <sup>*Torchwood* Season 1 Episode 1: "Everything Changes"</sup>

"Face the Raven" is its first (and, so far, only) mention in live-action *Doctor Who*. There is a reference to an "amnesia gas" in the 2009 animated special "Dreamland", which may be a prototype Retcon, but this isn't confirmed.